# Trying to plot stock data - getting a weird graph

Tags: python

I'm trying to plot stock data over a ten year period. I want the y-axis to have prices ranging from 0 to 32 and the x-axis to have the years from 2002 to 2012.

```
import csv, urllib.request, shutil, pandas as pd
import numpy as np, pylab as pl

url = "http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=YHOO&a=03&b=12&c=2006&d=01&e=9&f=2016&g=d&ignore=.csv"

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, open("C:/Examples/data.csv", 'wb') as out_file:
  shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)

with open("C:/Examples/data.csv", 'rb') as csvfile:
  df = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
  dates = df.Date;
  prices = df['Adj Close']
  x = [int(i[:4]) for i in dates] # int(i[:4]) to get the year part
  y = [p for p in prices]
  pl.xlim(2002, 2012)
  pl.ylim(0, 32.)
  pl.plot(x, y)
  pl.show()
```

When I print out the plot this is what I get.

[image]

I don't know if this is the correct output. I was expecting a somewhat smooth line starting from one side of the plot and going to the other. This is the stock csv file:

```
    Date    Open    High    Low     Close   Avg Vol Adj Close
Nov 1, 2012 16.90   19.16   16.86   18.77   27,813,200  18.77
Oct 1, 2012 16.00   16.89   15.65   16.84   23,074,600  16.84
Sep 4, 2012 14.64   16.20   14.59   15.98   21,900,500  15.98
Aug 1, 2012 15.86   16.37   14.59   14.65   17,527,600  14.65
Jul 2, 2012 15.80   16.17   15.23   15.84   15,348,400  15.84
Jun 1, 2012 15.04   15.83   14.81   15.83   14,102,700  15.83
May 1, 2012 15.51   16.00   14.80   15.24   19,935,500  15.24
Apr 2, 2012 15.19   15.70   14.73   15.54   16,640,200  15.54
Mar 1, 2012 14.89   15.61   14.35   15.22   15,408,200  15.22
Feb 1, 2012 15.57   16.31   14.37   14.83   22,020,900  14.83
Jan 3, 2012 16.27   16.39   15.35   15.47   18,167,300  15.47
Dec 1, 2011 16.42   16.46   14.57   16.13   21,943,000  16.13
Nov 1, 2011 14.95   16.50   14.75   15.71   24,382,900  15.71
Oct 3, 2011 13.70   16.79   13.37   15.64   36,438,000  15.64
Sep 1, 2011 13.67   15.40   12.45   13.17   42,743,300  13.17
Aug 1, 2011 13.24   13.98   11.09   13.61   33,473,700  13.61
Jul 1, 2011 15.08   15.95   13.04   13.10   29,550,000  13.10
Jun 1, 2011 16.34   16.43   14.50   15.04   25,772,600  15.04
May 2, 2011 17.79   18.84   15.63   16.55   41,113,700  16.55
Apr 1, 2011 16.83   17.77   16.06   17.70   20,728,700  17.70
Mar 1, 2011 16.46   17.70   15.81   16.68   25,018,300  16.68
Feb 1, 2011 16.33   17.84   16.04   16.40   24,578,700  16.40
Jan 3, 2011 16.81   17.34   15.41   16.12   23,201,900  16.12
Dec 1, 2010 16.00   17.22   16.00   16.63   12,970,200  16.63
Nov 1, 2010 16.50   17.60   15.77   15.82   21,166,800  15.82
Oct 1, 2010 14.19   16.76   14.13   16.49   29,726,500  16.49
Sep 1, 2010 13.20   14.53   13.13   14.17   27,527,400  14.17
Aug 2, 2010 14.01   14.52   12.94   13.11   13,811,800  13.11
Jul 1, 2010 13.99   15.60   13.52   13.88   24,186,600  13.88
Jun 1, 2010 15.31   15.84   13.79   13.84   21,523,300  13.84
May 3, 2010 16.68   16.99   14.63   15.34   26,797,300  15.34
Apr 1, 2010 16.58   19.12   16.22   16.53   33,650,200  16.53
Mar 1, 2010 15.43   16.94   15.40   16.53   21,831,600  16.53
Feb 1, 2010 15.14   15.71   14.48   15.31   21,501,000  15.31
Jan 4, 2010 16.94   17.30   14.90   15.01   24,600,000  15.01
Dec 1, 2009 15.03   16.99   14.85   16.78   18,305,700  16.78
Nov 2, 2009 15.75   16.36   14.80   14.97   20,043,500  14.97
Oct 1, 2009 17.65   18.02   15.74   15.90   25,250,700  15.90
Sep 1, 2009 14.50   17.94   13.97   17.81   36,378,300  17.81
Aug 3, 2009 14.56   15.21   14.30   14.61   28,097,800  14.61
Jul 1, 2009 15.49   17.68   14.22   14.32   36,381,400  14.32
Jun 1, 2009 16.17   16.99   14.55   15.66   19,810,700  15.66
May 1, 2009 14.50   15.84   13.91   15.84   24,369,700  15.84
Apr 1, 2009 12.70   15.39   12.60   14.29   24,663,000  14.29
Mar 2, 2009 12.85   14.14   12.31   12.81   20,620,800  12.81
Feb 2, 2009 11.50   14.00   11.49   13.23   18,837,100  13.23
Jan 2, 2009 12.17   13.56   10.81   11.73   21,408,600  11.73
Dec 1, 2008 11.82   13.57   10.50   12.20   20,089,400  12.20
Nov 3, 2008 12.74   14.89   8.94    11.51   31,084,900  11.51
Oct 1, 2008 17.17   17.31   11.25   12.82   32,771,500  12.82
Sep 2, 2008 19.63   20.82   16.88   17.30   24,333,600  17.30
Aug 1, 2008 20.09   20.82   18.87   19.38   13,981,900  19.38
Jul 1, 2008 20.48   24.80   19.59   19.89   30,010,200  19.89
```

Am I doing this the right way?

Comment: You're chopping your `date` x-values to the year, so I'm not surprised the values all stack up on those points. You probably need to preserve the month and day information in some form if you want a smooth graph.

Comment: Because you plot using just the year, lots of y-values end up at the same x position, and you end up with those vertical lines. Do you want to plot the mean in each year, or do you want the values spread out along the x-axis by using the actual dates for the x axis?

Comment: @Blckknght I figured that was it.

Comment: @Marius I want the values to spread out. I'm trying to plot the closing prices (`df['Adj Close']`) over these 10 years based on the dates.

Comment: You should be able to convert your date column to datetime format automatically using `x = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`, if you use datetimes as the x-axis matplotlib should handle them automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off using pandas' built-in date plotting:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

url = "http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=YHOO&a=03&b=12&c=2006&d=01&e=9&f=2016&g=d&ignore=.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(url)
df.index = df["Date"]
df.sort_index(inplace=True)

df['Adj Close'].plot()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. What does `sort_index` do?

Comment: It sorts the dataframe by the index. My first pass was plotting the values in reverse since Yahoo returns them with the most recent date on the left end of the X axis.

Comment: Why does it show the prices from 2006 to 2014 when the website I got it from shows it from 2002 to 2012?

Comment: Do you know how I would plot the rolling mean of this data?

Comment: `df['Adj Close'].rolling(100).mean().plot()` (where 100 is the window size)

Comment: I got the error "Series object has no attribute `rolling`"

Comment: My bad; looks like `.rolling()` isn't in the current stable release. You should be able to use `pd.rolling_mean` instead: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.rolling_mean.html (or alternatively, install the 0.18.0 dev release or build pandas from Github).

Comment: I used `rolling_mean` like this: `pd.rolling_mean(df.resample("1D", fill_method="ffill"), window=3, min_periods=1)` but it printed out the rolling mean to the console. I want to plot it like you've done but I don't know how. As for your other advice, I downloaded Anaconda yesterday and it came with Pandas, so what would I have to do to update it to the 0.18.0 release?

Comment: `pd.rolling_mean(df['Adj Close'], 100).plot()` should do it I think. If you're familiar with git, clone the repo, go to the folder, and run `python setup.py install` to install the bleeding edge version of pandas.